# Not able to run Android application on AVD

Tags: android

Hi I’m beginner in android development, I started learning it from www.developers.google.com
When I run any app on emulator (AVD). There is an error appname stopped working. What are the reasons is there any problem in my avd specification or something else my code is here :

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.secondlayout.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

   <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
   <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <string name="app_name">SecondLayout</string>
        <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
        <string name="button_send">Send</string>
        <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
        <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>

    </resources>
```

Comment: post your code and logcat error..

Comment: Check your logcat to provide a real stacktrace.

Comment: post your java code.

Comment: HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-12-04 11:44:34 - SecondLayout] Uploading SecondLayout.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-12-04 11:44:35 - SecondLayout] Installing SecondLayout.apk...
[2014-12-04 11:44:35 - SecondLayout] Success!
[2014-12-04 11:44:35 - SecondLayout] Starting activity com.example.secondlayout.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-12-04 11:44:41 - SecondLayout] Installation failed due to invalid URI!
[2014-12-04 11:44:41 - SecondLayout] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-12-04 11:44:42 - SecondLayout] Launch canceled!

Comment: @vandy this is console output am right.